# Chatter Tagging and Recently Viewed

Tags: chatter, recentlyviewed

According to [this documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_feed_slashrecord.htm&type=5), recently viewed items can be tagged in a Chatter post. And it works as described - if I've recently viewed something, I can tag it. The problem is that we'd like to be able to tag any record, not just recently viewed. Is there a way to have all records be searchable/taggable from the post?